# When or how does Pancham evolve?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I have leveled my Pancham up to level 40 but he has yet to evolve. Bulbapedia just shows that the pokemon evolves through an 'Unknown method.' I would like to know what the method is so that I can evolve my Pancham into Pangoro.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two conditions must be met in order for Pancham to evolve into Pangoro:

1. Pancham must be leveling to at least level 32.
2. A Pokémon with the Dark type must be in your party when Pancham levels up. It doesn't matter if it is Something/Dark as long as it has a dark type.

Comment: Took me a bit to find this information when I figured that he didn't evolve via normal leveling. Looks like it is on some other forums now. Hopefully putting it here will also help some people :)

Comment: For other Pokemon with weird evolutions, there's [this source](http://www.serebii.net/xy/evolution.shtml). Serebii is usually a very good resource for Pokemon stuff.

Comment: ...turn 3ds upside down when leveling up? That's... a new one.

Comment: I saw the turn upside down thing earlier too when I was looking up something. It is definitely rather unique, lol.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dark type such as Greninja in your party, and level up Pancham to 32 and he'll evolve.

Comment: While this may be *technically* correct, there is a more general answer than that.

Answer (score 0):

With a Dark-type Pokémon (such as Greninja) in the party, level Pancham up to or above level 32 with and it will evolve.

Answer (score 0):

Get a pancham and train it up to level 32 or higher. Then make sure you have a Pokemon that is pure dark or a combination of dark and another type in your party. Hope this helps.